# How to add a python script to the quick favorites menu?

Tags: python, scripting, quick-favorites

How can I make script work in quick favorites panel? I specifically need this simple script, that I learned to create after googling a bit of how to run it from the text editor, but I need it to be in the quick favorites instead.....

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.faces_select_linked_flat()

bpy.ops.mesh.region_to_loop()

bpy.ops.mesh.mark_sharp()
```

Because I hate to have to click every single time each option I use repeatedly to work with my models, so I hope someone can tell the trick to add this code as a quick favorites command.

Comment: guys can anyone tell me? this seems so simple to implement i think so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use [Script To Buttons](https://github.com/RivinHD/ScriptToButton/releases/tag/v2.0).

Create a button out of your script and add it to quick favorites panel. Done.

Comment: hello thanks yeah thats another option, but i used the Pie Menu Editor addon instead recently and it did the job very well, with just a shortcut and the command assigned to it it works...